# recode composite scores to scale groups

Tags: r, survey, consumer

I am new to this community, but I will try to explain my problem as clear as possible.I have conducted a consumer research in which I have a composite variable called, Consumer Innovativeness that is measured by 8 different question items. Each question item has 5 scale points(coded from "1" to "5"). However, when I had to create the composite variable, I created an average score for each respondent, using the command below (note: consumer innovativeness=numeric):

```
ConsumerInnovativeness <- with(ConsumerInnovativenessframe,(Q1_1 + Q1_2 + Q1_3 + Q1_4 + Q1_5 + Q1_6 + Q1_7 + Q1_8) / 8)
```

The result is the following data:

```
 [1] 2.625 2.875 2.875 3.125 1.000 1.375 3.125 1.625 3.875 3.375 2.500 4.000 3.250
[14] 3.125 4.375 3.500 3.250 3.875 2.750 3.625 3.000 2.875 2.875 4.250 2.500 3.375
[27] 3.250 2.750 2.625 2.875 3.625 1.375 3.500 3.500 1.875 3.125 2.625 3.375 2.000
[40] 2.375 2.625 2.250 2.875 2.000 3.250 3.125 4.000 2.125 3.125 3.875 2.875 1.750
[53] 2.125 2.250 2.250 3.250 3.250 2.125 2.125 3.500 2.750 1.875 4.000 3.125 2.500
[66] 2.875 1.875 2.625 2.125 3.375 2.875 1.500 2.375 2.125 3.875
```

Now, I want to use an Anova in order to see how the 5 different scale groups ("1" to "5") of Consumer Innovativeness differ in terms of another variable, called Perceived Creativity(numeric), and actually compare the means these 5 groups.
How can I cluster the averaged scores of Consumer Innovativeness into these 5 groups? I am looking forward to your suggestions.

Thank you in advance,

Jimmy.

Comment: You can use `cut` function to cut a numeric scale into categorical values. An improved `cut2` from `Hmisc` package actually does the factor conversion for you. BTW - you may want to look up on how to ask a question with reproducible examples so that people can provide working code in response.

Comment: thank you very much for the help!